# Reconciling the causality of QFT and the Feynman propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, causality, propagator, classical-field-theory

Unlike the retarded propagator, the Feynman propagator $\Delta_F(x-x^\prime)$ is given by $$\Delta_F(x-x^\prime)=\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_\textbf{p}}\Theta(t-t^\prime)e^{-ip\cdot(x-x^\prime)}+\Theta(t^\prime-t)e^{+ip\cdot(x-x^\prime)}$$ does not vanish when $t<t^\prime$.

As I understand, to maintain causality, the propagator (which is a Green's function) should vanish before the source $j(x)=\delta^{(4)}(x-x^\prime)$ was switched on i.e., for times $t<t^\prime$. How does it reconcile with the fact that quantum field theory is causal?

I understand that $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=0$ for spacelike separated points $x$ and $y$. This ensures causality. But why shouldn't I bother about the fact that $\Delta_F(x-x^\prime)\neq 0$ for $t<t^\prime$?

Comment: You don't use $\Delta_F$ to construct the out-states using the in-states. For that, you use the retarded propagator, precisely for the reason you say. The Feynman propagator is used to expand the correlation functions in perturbation theory, so there is no need for it to vanish for any $t$: the space-time variables are integration variables, with no physical meaning. In other words, there is nothing to reconcile.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform This answers my question except the point "the space-time variables are integration variables, with no physical meaning".

Comment: Well, the argument of the propagator always depends on variables over which you integrate, e.g., $S=\mathrm{Te}^{-i\int\mathrm dx\ \mathcal H_\mathrm{int}(x)}$. Even though we call $x$ a space-time coordinate, we may just as well perform the change of variables $x\to u$, in which case the propagators become $\Delta_F(u-u')$. In this case, it should be more or less clear that $u$ is an integration variable, with no real meaning, right?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I got one point that you made. Indeed, one can look, for example at how the Feynman propagator is generated once we consider the evolution operator in the interaction picture and then take the normal ordering. In the evolution operator originally one has $H_I(t)$'s, which are time ordered, which also requires tricky integration domains. If we take the normal ordering right there, then we get $\theta(t_1-t_2)\langle 0|phi_I(x_1,t_1)\phi_I(x_2,t_2)|0\rangle$.

Comment: However, to simplify the expression for the evolution operator one reorganises the integrals with more natural integration domains and puts the symbol of time ordering. And this is how the Feynman propagator occurs. So, I would say, the Feynman propagator does not represent a single process, but combines two processes, and this is just a convenient thing to do when we do computations, considering that the endpoints of the propagator are any way integrated over so we can rename $x_1\leftrightarrow x_2$ whenever convenient.

Comment: Still, I am puzzled with another thing: expressions like $\langle 0|\phi_I(x_1,t_1)\phi_I(x_2,t_2)|0\rangle$ are non-vanishing outside the light-cone. Does not that mean that particle has non-zero chance to travel faster than light?